# Windows api for identifying NVMe drive

Tags: powershell, winapi, nvme

Is there any windows api which returns if the drive is of nvme type? In powershell, when I do

```
Get-PhysicalDisk | select Friendlyname, BusType, MediaType
```

it gives the MediaType as `SSD` and the BusType as `RAID`. Ealier, I was using the `STORAGE_BUS_TYPE` win32 for checking NVMe by using the BusType, but I have an SSD Nvme device which has BusType as RAID.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried this kind of powershell command: `Get-PnpDevice | where { $_.InstanceId -like "SCSI\DISK&VEN_NVME&*"}`

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm a little late but have recently been working on a project and have come up with this which may help:

```
$bustype_table = @{ #bus type table taken from Microsofts webiste
    '0' = 'The bus type is unknown.'
    '1' = 'SCSI'
    '2' = 'ATAPI'
    '3' = 'ATA'
    '4' = 'IEEE 1394'
    '5' = 'SSA'
    '6' = 'Fibre Channel'
    '7' = 'USB'
    '8' = 'RAID'
    '9' = 'iSCSI'
    '10' = 'Serial Attached SCSI (SAS)'
    '11' = 'Serial ATA (SATA)'
    '12' = 'Secure Digital (SD)'
    '13' = 'Multimedia Card (MMC)'
    '14' = 'This value is reserved for system use (Virtual)'
    '15' = 'File-Backed Virtual'
    '16' = 'Storage spaces'
    '17' = 'NVMe'
}


try
{
    $windows_version = (Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem).Version #Gets windows version.
    if($windows_version -gt 10.0.00000) #has to be windows 10.0 or higher. wont work on 7 or 8.
   {
        $bustype = wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk get BusType #,Model
        $bustype_value = $bustype[2].Trim() #trims whitespace from the bustype value.
        $drive_connection = $bustype_table[$bustype_value] #calls the table.
     Write-Host "The C drive is connected via: $drive_connection `r`n"
    }
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message #windows version is pre windows 10. Script wont work.
}
```

Specifically, this is what you want I think:

```
wmic /namespace:\\root\microsoft\windows\storage path msft_disk get Model,BusType
```

Although, this may not work as you have stated that your NVMe drives are in raid so it may pick it up as '8' (RAID).

Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Forgot to add the Microsoft documentation link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/stormgmt/msft-disk?redirectedfrom=MSDN